# Would it be permissible to do autopsy on Prophet Muhammad's (pbuh) body?

Tags: halal-haram, prophet-muhammad, history

AFAIK, Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) is buried at [Green Dome in Medina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Dome). Given we've access to his body, would it be permissible, from an Islamic point of view, to conduct autopsy on his body/remains?

For example, via autopsy, we would be able to find out the era which he has lived in, his possible cause of death, and so on. If these are in-line with the Islamic tradition, they would be supporting points for the authenticity of Islamic history etc.

Comment: It’s definitely related. It seems to suggest that autopsy is not a valid reason to open a grave in the first place, am I right?

Comment: Both opening the grave and the acts involved in an autopsy are disrespectful and offensive against the prophet. It is not permitted.